# Selector is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I've HTML code which is

```
<div id="testing"></div>
<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" value="800">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_1" value="12/05/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_1" value="This is test notes">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_2" value="1500">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_2" value="12/10/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_2" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000001">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_3" value="1600">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_3" value="12/09/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_3" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000002">
```

Now I want to search a value in my notes fields which is `Towing amount paid Order ID 000000001` and I want to empty these fields and my javascript/jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     if($("input[name^=notes]").val().indexOf("Towing amount paid Order ID ") > -1) {
         $("#testing").text('found it');
         /*var current = $("input[name^=notes]");
         var onePrevious = $(current).prev();
         var twoPrevious = $(current).prev().prev();
         current.attr('value', '');
         onePrevious.attr('value', '');
         twoPrevious.attr('value', '');*/
     } else {
         $("#testing").text('not found');
     }
});
```

But this code is giving me `not found` message what is wrong in my code I've tried different selectors but didn't work for me.

Comment: You're only checking the first instance.

Comment: So how to check all fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code searches only in the input which has value - `This is test notes`.

To look in all fields use `$.each`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name^='notes']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf("Towing amount paid Order ID ") > -1) {
            $("#testing").text('found it');
        } else {
            $("#testing").text('not found');
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FakeHeal/362o548n/

Edit for clearing the fields: http://jsfiddle.net/FakeHeal/362o548n/1/

Comment: it worked for me and now I want to clear only those fields which have `Towing amount paid Order Id `, date and amount fields.

Comment: Just instead of this line `$("#testing").text('found it');`, add this `$(this).val('')`;

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery `:contains` pseudo it will find the first element that contains the required  text

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Code:

```
if($("input[name^='notes']:contains('Towing amount paid Order ID ')")) {
    $("#testing").text('found it');
} else {
    $("#testing").text('not found');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/La1bq789/

Comment: Man, this is pretty neat solution. Totally upvoting this. One question: it's well supported by the browsers?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova if I remember well is implemented by jQuery because it wa removed from CSS3 specs

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you checking only one element value and you need to check all elements.
I did make some changes with your code, now it's working:

```js
$("input[name^=notes]").each(function(){
  
if($(this).val().indexOf("Towing amount paid Order ID ") > -1) {
    $("#testing").text('found it');
    /*var current = $("input[name^=notes]");
    var onePrevious = $(current).prev();
    var twoPrevious = $(current).prev().prev();
    current.attr('value', '');
    onePrevious.attr('value', '');
    twoPrevious.attr('value', '');*/
} else {
    $("#testing").text('not found');
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing"></div>
<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" value="800">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_1" value="12/05/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_1" value="This is test notes">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_2" value="1500">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_2" value="12/10/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_2" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000001">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_3" value="1600">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_3" value="12/09/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_3" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000002">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input").each(function() {
       if ($(this).val().indexOf("Towing amount paid Order ID ") > -1) {
         $("#testing").text('found it');
         /*var current = $("input[name^=notes]");
         var onePrevious = $(current).prev();
         var twoPrevious = $(current).prev().prev();
         current.attr('value', '');
         onePrevious.attr('value', '');
         twoPrevious.attr('value', '');*/
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing"></div>
<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" value="800">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_1" value="12/05/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_1" value="This is test notes">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_2" value="1500">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_2" value="12/10/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_2" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000001">

<hr />
<hr />

<hr />
<hr />

<input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_3" value="1600">
<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_3" value="12/09/2015">
<input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_3" value="Towing amount paid Order ID 000000002">
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("input[name^=notes]").val()` will only ever return the value of the first element in the page than matches that selector.

In order to check all of them you need to look at each instance

I would suggest you modularize the repeating groups by wrapping each group in a container to help locate other related elements within each group

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_1" value="800">
    <input type="text" name="date[]" id="date_1" value="12/05/2015">
    <input type="text" name="notes[]" id="notes_1" value="This is test notes">
</div>
```

Then loop over the inputs you want to focus on

```
var hasNotes = $("input[name^=notes]").filter(function(){
      return this.value.indexOf("Towing amount paid Order ID ") > -1
}).length;
var message = hasNotes ? 'found it' :'not found'
$('#testing.text(message);
```

If you need to make adjustments to other values, use an `each` lopp and traverse within the container